# C# and .NET, classes declaration and member variable have same data-type as class name

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to learn and probably master C# and I came across the below class and member declaration and cannot wrap my head around.

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode(object value) // I know this is constructor
        { 
        this.Value = value;
        }

    public object Value { get; private set; } //member variable of type object

    public LinkedListNode Next { get; private set; }    //??? how can we declare a member variable type same as class name?? how does this works?
    public LinkedListNode Prev { get; internal set; } // class name us LinkedListNode and the member variable also has data-type LinkedListNode, im confused.
}
```

I came across this code in one the books for C#.
Kinldy assist.

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: The path to mastery is long :) There's nothing wrong with a type referencing itself. In fact, it's a pretty basic principle in the working of things like linked lists.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about a feature of a language, rather than presenting a problem to solve. Read the book more closely :)

Comment: Just remember that a class written in code is the expression of an object definition only.  A tree view is gonna blow your mind! :)

Comment: Thank for your response. My concern is  "public LinkedListNode Next {}", datatype has same name as classname. Im aware, how to initiated the one class in another class for e.g LinkedListNode linklistnode = new LinkedListNode(), but not familiar with the above concept. The book I'm referring is Wrox C# 2012 and .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a member variable of the same type as the class because, well, you can. At a compiler level, it just looks to see if that type is declared, and of course, it is! Note that this is a feature of C, C++, and if I had to guess, every other Object-Oriented language ever made.

One thing that you do need to know is that the default value of a reference type is `null`. This means that those member variables are null when a `LinkedListNode` is created. That avoids a recursive construction loop (which may be what you are confused about). This code:

```
public class LinkedListNode {
    public LinkedListNode(object value) // I know this is constructor
        { 
           this.Value = value;
           Next = new LinkedListNode("test"); //DONT DO THIS!!!
        }

    public object Value { get; private set; } //member variable of type object

    public LinkedListNode Next { get; private set; }    //??? how can we declare a member variable type same as class name?? how does this works?
    public LinkedListNode Prev { get; internal set; } // class name us LinkedListNode and the member variable also has data-type LinkedListNode, im confused.
}
```

Is a very good way to get a StackOverflowException, since the constructor creates a new object of the same type, ad infinitum.

In short, this is a very normal thing to do (just watch the potential recursion) and is something you should get used to seeing.